# Determine which network interface to use based on target IP

Tags: linux, networking

Say I have two network interfaces, `eth1` and `eth2`, both of them connected to a different ISP.

How can I instruct linux to use `eth1` for all traffic to the IP `111.222.111.222` while `eth2` is used for all other traffic?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the default route to the next hop on `eth2` and a separate route for `111.222.111.222`. Let's assume that 1.2.3.4 is the next hop for `eth1` then the command would be:

```
ip route add 111.222.111.222/32 via 1.2.3.4
```